# CoreData fetch request through abstract managed object to concrete managed object

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to execute a fetch request against a Managed Object Context with a predicate that tests against a keypath that exists in some subclasses of an abstract class.

For example here is a part of the object model

```
Library::NSManagedObject
 - AllMovies::to-many relationship->Movie

Movie::NSManagedObject (abstract)
 - type::String
 - name::String
 - mylibrary::to-one relationship->Library

HorrorMovie::Movie
 - monster::String
 - ghosts::BOOL

RomanceMovie::Movie
 - percociouskid::String
 - hasferret::BOOL
```

If I set up the following fetch request

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Library" 
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"(SUBQUERY(AllMovies, $movies, 
                                                   $movies.type like[c] 'horror' and
                                                   $movies.moster like[c] 'yeti'
                                       ).@count != 0)"
                          ] 
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Executing the fetch request returns an error like

```
keypath $movies.monster not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Movie id=2>
```

It doesn't seem like there is a way to do lazy evaluation of the predicate. Some of the other things I've already tried are an ANY predicate, using the CAST keyword, trying to replace 'AllMovies' in the SUBQUERY with another SUBQUERY to return a group of objects that matches the 'type' value.

It would be possible to do multiple requests for each qualifying type, but that is gross, slow and unwieldy.

This is under OS X 10.6 with an SQL persistent store. Doing an in memory store is not an option since I'm working with 1 million+ 'Libraries' (the project doesn't really have anything to do with movies but I thought it was a good example).

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work because your entity model just tells Core Data that the `AllMovies` relationship contains `Movie` objects. Therefore, Core Data expects to be able to send only those messages that a `Movie` object understands. When it instigates the fetch, it test the predicate against every single `Movie` object (as designated by the fetch entity.)

However, neither the `Movie` entity nor the `RomanceMovie` entity understand the `monster` message (because they lack the attribute.) The predicate test is rendered nonsensical. That is why you get the error.

You need to rethink your design. Using entity inheritance probably isn't the way you want to go with this.